# nodejs: do not wait spawned process

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am using `child_process.spawn` for running some app and I want to execute some actions after this app was started. But `spawn` blocks main process

```
const spawnAsync = Promise.promisify(require('child_process').spawn);
console.log('BEFORE');   
await spawnAsync('../node_modules/.bin/some-app', ['-p', '3333'], {
    detached: true
});
console.log('AFTER');
```

In my console, I see `BEFORE` and `AFTER` would be logged only after killing process on `3333` port. I don't want to wait spawned process, I want to do some actions after `spawnSync` calling.

Comment: Do you run this code **inside** async function?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: Well, it is not obvious from the code you have posted. :)

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear what you're asking.  If you don't want to wait for the spawned process to finish before executing the next line of code, then remove the `await`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) documentation you should use it that way

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');

const newProcessDescriptor = childProcess.spawn(
    '../node_modules/.bin/some-app', 
    ['-p', '3333'], 
    { detached: true }
);
      
newProcessDescriptor.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(`child process creating error with error ${error}`);
});

newProcessDescriptor.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```